# Choosing Best SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hi I am pretty New to MS SQL so forgive me if I am asking something which is very obvious to other more experienced people. I can write the query to fetch the data in multiple way to fetch the same data. Now I have two SQL queries X and Y which look like following

## (Query 1)

```
select column1, column2, column3
from 
Table1 a
inner join 
Table2 b on a.column1=b.column1
where Condition1 and condition2

EXCEPT

(select column1, column2, column3
from 
Table1 a
inner join 
Table2 b on a.column1=b.column1
where Condition3
)
```

## (Query 2)

```
select column1, column2, column3
from 
Table1 a
inner join 
Table2 b on a.column1=b.column1
where Condition1 and condition2

And column1 Not in 
(select column1
from 
Table1 a
inner join 
Table2 b on a.column1=b.column1
where Condition3
)
```

These both take similar time and Estimated Subtree cost also have minimal difference. I am not sure which one is a better query and why.

Comment: I Would expect query 2 to perform a little better since it has to compare less data than query 1. Unless one of the columns is the primary key, then it will be smart enough to only use that one.

Comment: What column(s) does the conditions operate on? And which table do you select from?

Comment: Also keep in mind is that `EXCEPT` includes an implicit `DISTINCT`. Which means that duplicate rows from the left table will be removed. That is not the case for query 2.

Answer (score 2):

**EXCEPT** compares all (paired)columns of two full-selects and returns distinct rows from left result set which are not present in the right result set, while **NOT IN** compares two or more tables according to the conditions specified in WHERE clause in the sub-query following *NOT EXISTS* keyword and does the same however it doesn’t returns the distinct result set.

The **EXCEPT** returns distinct rows whereas **NOT IN** didn’t return distinct values. If you analyse the execution plan, you will realise that the **EXCEPT** query is ***slower*** than **NOT IN**.

The distinct sort operator in the EXCEPT costs around 65% of the total execution time.

According to this [Link](http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1635857-difference-between-except-and-Not-exists), **EXCEPT** can be rewritten by using **NOT EXISTS**. (**EXCEPT ALL** can be rewritten by using **ROW_NUMBER** and **NOT EXISTS**.)

Refer to [LINK](http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/except-vs-not-in-performance-in-sql-server/) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Things are much clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

Second one seems to have a slight edge on the first one.
The sub-query in second one fetches only one column i.e. column1.
If that column is indexed then it will be far better for sql engine to query with precision and speed.

Answer (score 0):

What if you modify the where condition like below?

```
select column1, column2, column3
from 
Table1 a
inner join 
Table2 b on a.column1=b.column1
where Condition1 and condition2 and not condition 3
```